# form_tag in haml creates form with no inputs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

The app is rails 3. After a js response the following snippet is rendered within a div:

```
  = form_tag("/admin/limits/change/#{user.id}", :remote => "true") do
    %th{:scope => "row"}= index+1
    %td= user.email
    %td.text-center= user.domain || "null"
    %td.text-center
      = check_box :details, 'limit', { :checked => (user.details && user.details.limit.eql?("hard")) }, 'hard', 'soft'
    %td.text-center
      = button_tag 'Set limit' , class: 'btn' , type: :submit
```

The problem is the form seems to ignore the `do` statement. None of the content indented after is included in it. It's just an empty form with no submit. All following lines, including `check_box` and `button_tag`, are rendered outside.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/limits/change/5" data-remote="true" method="post"></form>
```

Tried with `submit_tag` instead of `button_tag` but does not fix the issue. Neither adding `form_tag .. do |f|`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you should have used check_box_tag since its a form_tag, also using do is fine, also you need to indent the %td tags inside the %th

```
 = form_tag("/admin/limits/change/#{user.id}", :remote => "true") do
   %th{:scope => "row"}= index+1
     %td= user.email
     %td.text-center= user.domain || "null"
     %td.text-center= check_box_tag :details, 'limit', { :checked = (user.details && user.details.limit.eql?("hard")) }, 'hard', 'soft'
     %td.text-center= button_tag 'Set limit' , class: 'btn' , type: :submit
```

Comment: thanks @behraang but no, that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: form still looks empty of inputs: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/admin/limits/change/5" data-remote="true" method="post"></form>